# Why is the form_load event is not called in my Winforms application?

Tags: winforms

I don´t know why, but my form isn´t calling Form_Load event when it loads.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Dumb question - you're calling Show or ShowDialog on it, right?  Maybe you could post a snippet of your code - might help us help you.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have the event handler set up?

Ultimately, there is going to be a line of code that looks something like this:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

That might be something you code yourself, or is generated by double-clicking the Load event for the form from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an exception is being thrown in Initialize_Component(); which prevents the on load method being called?

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/20/the-case-of-the-disappearing-onload-exception-user-mode-callback-exceptions-in-x64/

Answer (score 0):

go to the btnSave
find "Click"
set "btnSave_Click"
then works